# How can I return the next move in the alpha-beta algorithm?

Tags: prolog, tic-tac-toe, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm implementing an AI to play Tic Tac Toe and I'm using the alpha-beta algorithm to search for the best move. Below is the code I have so far. I managed to make the algorithm work -- the value of the states seems to be correct, but I'm not being able to return the right next move/board.

When I execute the goal `Board = ['-','-','-','o','-','-','-','-','-'], alpha_beta(max, Board, V, NB).`, this is the output:

```
?- Board = ['-','-','-','o','-','-','-','-','-'], alpha_beta(max, Board, V, NB).

Board = [-, -, -, o, -, -, -, -, -],
V = 0,
NB = [-, -, -, o, -, -, -, -, x].
```

The value `V` is correct (it indicates that the result of the match will be a draw), **but NB, which represents the next move of the 'x' player, is not.**

**Testing, I beat the AI, what shouldn't have happened.** In the image I executed the goal several times simulating a Tic Tac Toe match. The AI plays with the 'x' symbol. About the output: the first board is the current board, the board provided as input and the second one is the `NextBoard`, the move made by the AI:

[image: Testing the AI]

I've tried a few things. I tried to use `guitracer`, I tried to read other implementations, but I can't find a solution for my implementation. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
alpha_beta(max,Board,Value, NextBoard):-
    ab_minimax(max,Board,-inf,inf,Value, NextBoard).
    
ab_minimax(max,Board,_,_,-1, NextBoard):-
    is_winning_state_o(Board), !.
ab_minimax(min,Board,_,_,1, NextBoard):-
    is_winning_state_x(Board), !. 
ab_minimax(_,Board,_,_,0, NextBoard):-
    is_a_draw(Board), !.
ab_minimax(max,Board,Alfa,Beta,Value, NextBoard):-
    children(Board, max, Children),
    ab_max_children(Children,Alfa,Beta,-inf,Value, NB, NextBoard).
ab_minimax(min,Board,Alfa,Beta,Value, NextBoard):-
    children(Board, min, Children),
    ab_min_children(Children,Alfa,Beta,inf,Value, NB, NextBoard).

ab_max_children([],_,_,Max,Max, NextBoard, NextBoard).
ab_max_children([H|T],Alfa,Beta,Max1,Max, NB, NextBoard):-
    ab_minimax(min,H,Alfa,Beta,Value, NextBoardX),
    ( 
        Value > Beta -> % Beta cut
            Max = Beta,
            NextBoard = H
        ; (
            max(Value,Alfa,Alfa1), % updates Alpha
            max(Value,Max1,Max2),
            (Max2 == Value -> NB1 = H; NB1 = NB),
            ab_max_children(T, Alfa1, Beta, Max2, Max, NB1, NextBoard)
        )
    ).

ab_min_children([],_,_,Min,Min, NextBoard, NextBoard).
ab_min_children([H|T],Alfa,Beta,Min1,Min, NB, NextBoard):-
    ab_minimax(max,H,Alfa,Beta,Value, NextBoardX),
    (
        Alfa > Value -> % Alpha cut
            Min = Alfa,
            NextBoard = H
        ; (
            min(Value,Beta,Beta1), % updates Beta
            min(Value,Min1,Min2),
            (Min2 == Value -> NB1 = H; NB1 = NB),
            ab_min_children(T, Alfa, Beta1, Min2, Min, NB1, NextBoard)
        )
    ).

is_winning_state_x(S) :-
    winning_state_x(S), !.

winning_state_x(['x','x','x',_,_,_,_,_,_]). % [1,2,3]
winning_state_x([_,_,_,'x','x','x',_,_,_]). % [4,5,6]
winning_state_x([_,_,_,_,_,_,'x','x','x']). % [7,8,9]
winning_state_x(['x',_,_,'x',_,_,'x',_,_]). % [1,4,7]
winning_state_x([_,'x',_,_,'x',_,_,'x',_]). % [2,5,8]
winning_state_x([_,_,'x',_,_,'x',_,_,'x']). % [3,6,9]
winning_state_x(['x',_,_,_,'x',_,_,_,'x']). % [1,5,9]
winning_state_x([_,_,'x',_,'x',_,'x',_,_]). % [3,5,7]

is_winning_state_o(S) :-
    winning_state_o(S), !.

winning_state_o(['o','o','o',_,_,_,_,_,_]). % [1,2,3]
winning_state_o([_,_,_,'o','o','o',_,_,_]). % [4,5,6]
winning_state_o([_,_,_,_,_,_,'o','o','o']). % [7,8,9]
winning_state_o(['o',_,_,'o',_,_,'o',_,_]). % [1,4,7]
winning_state_o([_,'o',_,_,'o',_,_,'o',_]). % [2,5,8]
winning_state_o([_,_,'o',_,_,'o',_,_,'o']). % [3,6,9]
winning_state_o(['o',_,_,_,'o',_,_,_,'o']). % [1,5,9]
winning_state_o([_,_,'o',_,'o',_,'o',_,_]). % [3,5,7]

has_empty_position(['-'|_]) :- !.
has_empty_position([_|T]) :- has_empty_position(T).

is_a_draw(S) :-
    not(has_empty_position(S)).

children(Board, Player, Children) :-
    findall(NewBoard, make_move(Player, Board, NewBoard), Children).

make_move(max, ['-'|T], ['x'|T]).
make_move(min, ['-'|T], ['o'|T]).
make_move(Player, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :- make_move(Player, T1, T2).
```

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Please correct them. Also please describe what you want. You can start by adding a question and the answer you expect.

Comment: @tiffi Oh, it may have been a copy-paste error. I correct them and provided more information about the input and the output.

Comment: Thank you. I still have the problem that you didn't give your definition of  is_winning_state_o/1.

Comment: @tiffi Added in the end now :)

Comment: After adding clauses for `min/3` and  `max/3` (     `min(A,B,A):- A<B, !. 
    min(_,B,B).
    max(A,B,A):- A>B, !. 
    max(_,B,B).` ),
I can now reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a question - what do you expect with `?- Board = [x,o,x,o,x,o,_,_,_], alpha_beta(max, Board, V, NB).` ?

Comment: @tiffi I would expect `NB = [x, o, x, o, x, o, -, -, x]` or `NB = [x, o, x, o, x, o, x, -, -]`.

Comment: Actually, any of the three possibilities (`NB = [x, o, x, o, x, o, -, x, -]` also, in addition to the two above), because all of them leads to 'x' winning. In this state, there is no way in which 'o' wins or the match ends in a draw.

Comment: However, I get Board = [x, o, x, o, x, o, o, o, o], V = -1 . NB was not unified with anything. Maybe that's a valuable hint.

Comment: Ahm, that's weird.

Comment: Oh, I know what happened! You need to put the symbols in single quotes.

`?- Board = ['x','o','x','o','x','o','-','-','-'], alpha_beta(max, Board, V, NB).
Board = [x, o, x, o, x, o, -, -, -],
V = 1,
NB = [x, o, x, o, x, o, -, -, x].`

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification! I don't need single quotes, but can definitely not use Variables, where there should be '-'. [Try ?-'x'=x.]

Comment: Oh, yes, that was it. You were using `_` (underscore) instead of `-` (dash) in the board empty positions.

Comment: Do you have a link to a good explanation of alpha-beta-pruning with regard to tic-tac-toe or some well-written working code example in another language?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what the "right" next move is, since there is often more than one optimal move.

What you are doing is to evaluate your board's children. The above table shows each of the children with their Value, the current Alpha and the current Beta:

```
  [[x,-,-,o,-,-,-,-,-],0,-inf,inf]
  [[-,x,-,o,-,-,-,-,-],0,0,inf]
  [[-,-,x,o,-,-,-,-,-],0,0,inf]
  [[-,-,-,o,x,-,-,-,-],0,0,inf]
  [[-,-,-,o,-,x,-,-,-],0,0,inf]
  [[-,-,-,o,-,-,x,-,-],0,0,inf]
  [[-,-,-,o,-,-,-,x,-],0,0,inf]
  [[-,-,-,o,-,-,-,-,x],0,0,inf]
```

Since all children have the same value, the next board is of course the last child.

There are two problems:

1. You implement it in such a way that for each Board, you have at most one Nextboard, whereas there could be more than one optimal next board.
2. I think that you evaluate the children incorrectly. When I am running good old minimax, I get:

```
[x,-,-,o,-,-,-,-,-]  0
[-,x,-,o,-,-,-,-,-] -1
[-,-,x,o,-,-,-,-,-] -1
[-,-,-,o,x,-,-,-,-] 0
[-,-,-,o,-,x,-,-,-] 0
[-,-,-,o,-,-,x,-,-] 0
[-,-,-,o,-,-,-,x,-] -1
[-,-,-,o,-,-,-,-,x] -1
```

Shouldn't Alpha-beta pruning only cut off considering certain alternatives and thus making the search faster, but yield the same results?